# NULL vs empty string

Tags: sql-server

What is the difference between the below queries & how it works?

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE col IS NOT NULL
```

&

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE col <> ''
```

Regards,
Mubarak

Answer (score 8):

The `NULL` is special data type, it means absence of value.

An empty string on the other hand means a string or value which is empty.

Both are different.

For example, if you have `name` field in table and by default you have set it to `NULL`. When no value is specified for it, it will be `NULL` but if you specify a real name or an empty string, it won't be `NULL` then, it will contain an empty string instead.

Comment: thanks for your response. Could you please explain with example?

Comment: @user873779: I have given an example in my answer but it can be best understood when you try it out. Create a table, create a field in it, set its default value to `NULL`. Create two records for it one with no data eg `NULL` and one with empty string and run your query.

Comment: Think about a hospital patient. When a new baby is born and s/he does not have a name yet ideally you would put an empty string. The system knows that this patient does not have a name. If a person comes to the emergency room with no identification etc. ideally you would put null in the name column. The system does not know this patient's name.

Answer (score 5):

`NULL` is the absence of value, and usually indicates something meaningful, such as unknown or not (yet) determined. For example, if I start a project today, the `StartDate` is `2012-02-25`. If I don't know how long the project is going to take, what should the `EndDate` be? I might have some idea what the `ProjectedEndDate` may be, but I would set the `EndDate` to `NULL`, and update it when the project is complete.

`''` is a zero-length (or "empty") string. It is not technically the absence of data, since it might actually be meaningful. For example, if I don't have a middle name, depending on your data model `''` might make more sense than `NULL` since the latter implies unknown but `''` can imply that it is known that I don't have one. `NULL` can be used the same way of course, but then it is difficult to decipher whether it is not known whether it exists, or known that it does not exist. A lot of standards have dedicated values for things where it might not be known - for example `Gender` has I believe 9 different character codes so that if `M` or `F` are not specified, we always know exactly why (unknown, unspecified, transgender, etc). Also think of the case where `HeartRate` is `NULL` - is it because there was no pulse, or because we haven't taken it yet?

They are not the same, though unfortunately many people treat them the same. If your column allows `NULL` it means that you know in advance that sometimes you may not know this information. If you are not treating them as the same thing, then your queries would differ. For example if `col` does not allow `NULL`, your first query will always return all results in the table, since none of them can be `NULL`. However `NOT NULL` still allows an empty string to be entered unless you have also set up a check constraint to prevent zero-length strings also.

Allowing both for the same column is usually a bit confusing for someone trying to understand the data model, though I believe in most cases a `NOT NULL` constraint is not combined with a `LEN(col)>0` check constraint. The problem if both are allowed is that it is difficult to know what it means if the column is `NULL` or the column is "empty" - they *could* mean the same thing, but they may not - and this will vary from shop to shop.

Another key point is that `NULL` compared to anything (at least by default in SQL Server`*`) evaluates to unknown, which in turn evaluates to false. As an example, these queries *all* return `0`:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(i INT);
INSERT @x VALUES(NULL);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @x WHERE i = 1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @x WHERE i <> 1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @x WHERE i <= 3;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @x WHERE i > 3;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @x WHERE i IN (1,2,3);
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @x WHERE i NOT IN (1,2,3);
```

Since the comparisons in the where clause always evaluate to unknown, they always come back false, so no rows ever meet the criteria and all counts come back as `0`.

In addition, the answers to this question on dba.stackexchange might be useful:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/why-shouldnt-we-allow-nulls

`*` You can change this by using `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` - however this is not advised both because it provides non-standard behavior and because this "feature" [has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and will become a no-op in a future version of SQL Server. But you can play with the query above and see that the `NOT IN` behaves differently with `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`.

Comment: HeartRate example is spot on.

Answer (score 2):

NULL means the value is missing but '' means the value is there but just empty string
so first query means query all rows that col value is not missing, second one means select those rows that col not equals empty string

Update

For further information, I suggest you read this article:

https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2007/07/null-the-databases-black-hole/

Answer (score 1):

`Select * from table where col IS NOT NULL`would return results excluded from `Select * from table where col <> ‘’` because an empty string is also NOT NULL.

Comment: thanks for your response. Could you please explain with example?

Answer (score 0):

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62491/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-9444638-null-vs-empty-in-sql-server

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE (value varchar(50) NULL, description varchar(50) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (NULL, 'A Null'), ('', 'Empty String'), ('Some Text', 'A non-empty string');

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
SELECT * FROM @tbl WHERE value IS NOT NULL;
SELECT * FROM @tbl WHERE value <> '';
```

Note that in the display you cannot distinguish between NULL and '' - this is only an artifact of how the grid and text client display the data, but the data in the set is stored differently for NULL and ''.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers, `NULL` means 'no value' while empty string `''` means just that - empty string. You can think of fields that allow `NULLs` as optional fields - they can be ignored and value for them may just not be provided.

Imagine an application where respondent selects their title (Mr, Mrs, Miss, Dr) but you do not require him/her to select any of those and leave it blank. In this case you would put NULL into relevant database field.

Distinction between `NULL` and empty string may not be obvious because they both can mean 'no value' if you decide to. It depends entirely up to you but using `NULL` would be better mainly because it is a special case for databases which are designed to handle NULLs quickly and efficiently (much faster than strings). If you use it instead of an empty string your queries will be faster and more reliable.